# Login error for Azure SQL from an application service

Tags: authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I did my first deployment to an Azure App Service using Github CI/CD.  The application comes up, but shows a 500 error. In Application Insights I see an error for "login failed for user ".

What I have tried:

1. I reset the Sql Server password
2. I can login using the same id and password using SSMS.
3. I can login using the same id and password in Azure Database query editor.
4. I checked the connection string in the Azure app service Configuration > Connection String. The username and password is correct.

FYI, the password is in the format of @.  I use the exact same format to connect via SSMS and Query Editor.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Update**
Here is the connection string in Azure app service config.  I should have included that earlier. `Data Source=tcp:congresssucksdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=congresssucks_db;User Id=************;Password=***************`

The stack is .Net 6 and EF 6

The firewall settings look right
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code and which runtime stack you are using?

Comment: Please post the connection string (with user, password and the host piece of the server redacted)

Comment: @USMC6072, Reset the password and try again. I was getting the same error and I could fix it by resetting the password.

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya I want to try the config fixes first.  I could be wrong, but I don't think its a code issue.

Comment: @PravallikaKV thanks for reminding me.  I did try and reset the password before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled [diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656)? It can really help you determine what is the cause of the issue.

You can also use Visual Studio [debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656) remotely to create traces and obtain detailed error messages.

Make sure you configure Azure SQL Database firewall to allow access to Azure services.

[image]

Comment: I added a snip of the firewall settings and it looks right.  I'll try the additional logging as well.  I attempted setting up remote debugging a while back and couldn't get it to work.  I'll try it again.

Comment: I hope you can find the way to make it work in your environment, it can help you a lot troubleshooting Web Apps in the future also. Try also diagnostics logging.

Comment: I finally got remote debugging to connect but haven't been able to get breakpoints to work.  Looking into the symbols.. anyway, I looked through the output window and got the same error message.  "Login failed for user....".  No luck with the detailed error logging either.  No new info gained.

Comment: Let's try Auditing now, if you still have some time available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627413/azure-sql-database-error-18456-state-122-causes-failed-connections-to-database/58632579#58632579

Comment: I was mistaken and I am getting debug logging in azure.  It might be a problem with my userId.  When I created the AzureSql I think it defaulted my username to my email, or I might have done it, but the extra "@" might be an issue.  I'm going to change my username and see what happens.

Comment: Try with a contained user SQL login CREATE USER YourUserName  
WITH PASSWORD='Enterpwdhere*'. Add the user to database reader role ( EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'YourUserName';) and try again with the contained user.

Comment: Ugh I HATE this.  None of the comments suggested an answer so I blew away everything in my Resource Group and did a new deploy from Visual Studio.  Its in even worse shape now.  I'm abandoning this question since the scope has changed.  Thanks so much for everyone's help.